# How to stop ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, cpu, ruby

When I run a faulty ruby loop programme, my CPU start running fast as you can see in the following image. I stop abort it by `ctrl C` but it keep running. Only I can stop it to restart the computer.

Is there any way to stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to kill it from the command line.

```
kill -9 [PID]
```

Where PID is, in this case, 3562.

I don't have a Mac handy, but I believe you can also kill it directly from Activity Monitor.  If you select the process, you should be able to right click on it and send it a `SIGKILL`, or more directly you should be able to quit the app by clicking the `X` button, if I recall correctly.

Comment: The Force Quit option in Activity Monitor should do this, too.